# Velocity profile of Orifice meter

Tags: fluid-statics

Can someone tell me what will be the velocity profile in orifice meter?I am confused about the downstream side velocity of fluid.What i am thinking is downstream there is a pressure loss in the orifice,so velocity must be greater than upstream side of the orifice.
Am i correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orifice_plate

Comment: Lav Kumar Yadav, please clarify your problem statement.  Are you asking about incompressible flow (liquids) or compressible flow (gases)?

Answer (score 0):

Differential pressure across the orafice plate is higher upstream of the plate(restriction to flow)
and lower downstream. Any fluids text can explain the ramifications in easy to understand terms. 
YouTube also has many relevant videos.

Comment: I understand this but i m talking about velocity at downstream where pressure is almost recovered.

Comment: After equalization of flow (approx. Ten pipe diameters down stream) flow characteristics of the upstream flow profile will obviously match. The orafice plate size determines the overall thruput of the piping, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli equation neglects viscous/turbulent drag by considering the fluid to be inviscid.  In the case of an orifice meter, even though there is a pressure drop across the plate, this pressure drop is solely the result of viscous/turbulent drag.  Therefore, the velocity downstream can equal the velocity upstream, even though there is a pressure decrease.